# Not sure what to change to let a char break statement

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop

I'm setting up my while loop and it's supposed to break off if you enter 'q' or 'Q', only way i could get it to work is if I set "number" to a `char` instead of an `int`. If I change it to char, everything goes full on whacky. Here's what it looks like. Currently if i press 'q' to break, it goes into an infinite rambling

```
    int maximum = 0, sum = 0, odd = 0, even = 0, minimum = 0, count = 0;
    int number;
    char q, Q;


    while (1)
    {
        cout << "Enter a series of number, then type Q to process: "; cin >> number;

        if (number == 'q')
            break;
```

I need it to be something along the lines of;

```
if (number == 'q' | | number == 'Q')
 cout << "No Numbers were pressed";
 break;
```

Also, to make a variable undefined, it was giving me errors. I need `maximum` and `minimum` to be undefined so if the user doesn't go above 0 for either it wont say their maxinmum number pressed was 0. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand how stream operators work. `cin >> number` will want your input to be numeric (and decimal for that matter). If you give it `Q`, it doesn't accept it, and will not modify `number`.

If you want your input to be both numeric and string, you will have to first read it is an `std::string`, check the string for being equal `"q"` (**NB** - as a string, in quotes, not as a character!), and if it is not, convert string to integer - in C++11 you can use `std::stoi`.

Answer (score 1):

std::cout will not read a character into an int variable. In other words, this code will never work. You can either change the input to a string and parse it into an int (stoi is useful here) or have two separate reads, one into a char and one into an int.

Comment: An integer CAN hold a character value.   The difference is that integers and characters are read differently.

Comment: I might have phrased that wrong, I guess I meant that std::cin will not read a character as an int value.

Comment: @JacobH, than you'd better edit it, because right now your answer is very misleading.

Answer (score -1):

you need

```
string input;
int num;
cout << "Enter a series of number, then type Q to process: ";
while(true)
{
 cin >> input;
 if(input == "q" || input == "Q")
    break;
 num = strtol(input.c_str());
 .....
}
```

Comment: There's no standard function called `strtoi`  (and a quick survey of non-standard functions of that name shows none accepting a single `char` argument)